# Apply Custom Number Formatting to Error values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply a custom number format to cells in Excel 2007 that return an error value.

I understand that I can apply custom number formatting to number/text values in the form POSITIVE;NEGATIVE;ZERO;TEXT. However, it seems that error values don't fit into any of these four categories. I know also that I can apply a formatting of "[condition]format", but I can't find any way to test for the presence of an error.

Microsoft has [a couple of workarounds](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-error-values-and-error-indicators-in-cells-d171b96e-8fb4-4863-a1ba-b64557474439), but all of them require either converting the error to another value or else formatting the result as white text, which is unreliable for situations where the background isn't also white.

Is there any way to apply custom number formatting so that a cell can *contain* an error value but *display* nothing? If the answer is no, why not?

Comment: "If the answer is no, why not?" - this is definitely not a question we can answer here, simply because it depends only on Microsoft how they implement it. If you have access to conditional formatting then probably can change formulas too, why not just add `IFERROR(<original formula>,"")` and that would automatically convert all errors to blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

Because Microsoft decided so, and probably because it is dangerous for less qualified users - they would not see the error anymore.

What you can do - if you don't want the recommended `IFERROR(<original formula>,"")` - is to make a *conditional formatting* on the cell, where you use the formula `=ISERROR(cell)` and the resulting format *white text on white background*.

Again, there is the danger of forgetting it, or the next user not knowing it. In large sheets, this is the stuff that nightmares are build from...

Comment: In the second formula you could want to write `ISERROR`.

Comment: Does Microsoft (or someone else) have any documentation of the inability to format error values using custom number formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have the formula in cell **B2**

```
=B1/A1
```

[image]

We apply conditional formatting to **B2** with the FormulaIs Option:

[image]

Now for divide-by-zero:

[image]